# Workflow calculation - number of days based on TODAY

Tags: 2013, workflow, calculated-column

I initially tried to create this as a Calculated Column.  But, of course, they don't like [Today] as a variable.  I'm trying to populate a column with a number that is a calculation based upon a date someone enters into another column.  So the calculation would be:

```
[Today] - [PastDate]
```

With the impossibility of creating this in a Calc Column, I'm now looking at a workflow for this (using Nintex, of course).  How would I go about doing this calculation in a workflow (since that seems to be my only option) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on many references on this in Stack Exchange,
you can use Today() instead of [Today] like:

```
=TODAY()-DateOne
```

Comment: Thank you, Matiur .

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Martiur's response, to calculate the number of days you can use the DateDif function:

```
=DATEDIF(Start_date,End_date,"D") -> "D" for number of days.
```

E.g.:

1. Create a calculated column of type number
2. Formula

> =DATEDIF(Today(),[PastDate],"D")

[Microsoft Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c)

Comment: That's good to know.  Thank you.